# Empty File Created without text in .txt file in .NET Core

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, streamwriter, memorystream

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
           var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
           sw.Write("Hi");
           ms.Position = 0;
           return File(ms, "text/plain", "file.txt");
        }
}
```

**Result: I get an empty text file**

> Tried Code- var sw = new StreamWriter(ms,Encoding.UTF8,1024,true)

> return File(stream.ToArray(), "text/plain", "file.txt");

*Nothing seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.*

Comment: first of all isnt  it supposed to get the file/download it? why is it httppost

Comment: @aaarianme, based on that id i fetch some result from database and write those data in text file. I'm calling this method from ajax post.

Comment: Haven't used .net in a while, but possibly the stream writer didn't flush to memory stream? Try putting it in a using block

Comment: @T.Aoukar, will get ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream issue.

Comment: There was a parameter to tell writer not to close stream on dispose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
            sw.Write("Hi");
            ms.Position = 0;
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();               
            return File(ms.GetBuffer(), "text/plain", "file.txt");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Can you explain me the issue and is there a way i can use using statement in here ?

Comment: Hi @crazyCoder,you need to use `sw.Flush();` to flush it in the Stream out to the file.